# Close map from a button on a toolbar in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, button, maps

I have an application where if I press a button I will go to maps, I was able to do that, and in my map view I have a toolbar which has a button "back" which is supposed to get me back to the previous view, however I'm having difficulties doing that because I can't seem to find an appropriate function to do it, or maybe I missed, Its my first time working with maps and multiple views for an iOS app. Can someone help me please with how to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to dismiss the view controller.

If you're presenting the map modally, have the back button call a method that performs:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```